# Gradle won't import a bintray dependency, but doesn't throw any error

Tags: java, maven, gradle, kotlin

I'm creating a project which uses the [Squash](https://github.com/orangy/squash) SQL Library for Kotlin. I've added the dependency to my `build.gradle` file. When running the update it just finishes without outputting any errors. But the library is not getting imported in my project and doesn't appear at all.

The dependencies shown in IntelliJ:

[image]

My `build.gradle` file:

```
//Kotlin Stuff, nothing changed here

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/squash"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.squash:squash:0.2.2'
}

//Kotlin Stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency you've added is just the parent-pom which doesn't have any jar's in the repo. Here is the list of the `squash` projects (http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/squash/org/jetbrains/squash/):

- `squash-core`
- `squash-graph`
- `squash-h2`
- `squash-jdbc`
- `squash-postgres`
- `squash-sqlite`

I guess you want to import the `squash-core` so change

```
compile 'org.jetbrains.squash:squash:0.2.2'
```

to

```
compile 'org.jetbrains.squash:squash-core:0.2.2'
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense